# TypeError with .map and The Movie Database

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui, array.prototype.map

I am learning programming since a few months and I am starting to practice with some projects that I could create by myself or that I could find on the internet to study and learn more about different topics. In this case, I am working with React.js, Material UI and The Movie Database trying to make some kind of website related to movies and series. I was doing fine, until I needed to display all the genres and filter them on the page.

My intention is to display all the genres from The Movie Database and filter them when I needed. In some cases this code works fine and without any issue but in general it says that "genres.map is not a function" and the component doesn't render.

I know that this type of error normally happens when I try to map something that it is not an array. However, in this case genres IS an array. The most annoying thing for me is that in some rare cases the code works fine.
As I said before, I am new relatively new to programming and it is my first question here so I apologize if this is not the place to ask this. I would be very grateful if someone could help me to solve this and most important to understand what is the problem.

```
import { Chip } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Genres = ({
  selectedGenres,
  setSelectedGenres,
  genres,
  setGenres,
  type,
  setPage,
}) => {

  const addGenre = (genre) => {
    setSelectedGenres([...selectedGenres, genre]);
    setGenres(genres.filter((g) => g.id !== genre.id));
    setPage(1);
  };

  const removeGenre = (genre) => {
    setSelectedGenres(
      selectedGenres.filter((selected) => selected.id !== genre.id)
    );
    setGenres([...genres, genre]);
    setPage(1);
  };

  const fetchGenres = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/${type}/list?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`
    );
    setGenres(data.genres);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchGenres();

    return () => {
      setGenres({});
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  console.log(genres);

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "6px 0" }}>
      {selectedGenres.map((genre) => (
          <Chip
            label={genre.name}
            style={{ margin: 2 }}
            size="small"
            key={genre.id}
            clickable
            onDelete={() => removeGenre(genre)}
          />
        ))}
      {genres.map((genre) => (
          <Chip
            label={genre.name}
            style={{ margin: 2 }}
            size="small"
            key={genre.id}
            clickable
            onClick={() => addGenre(genre)}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Genres;
```

Answer (score 0):

`genres` must either consistently be an array, or your code must handle cases that are not an array. In your case the problem is here:

```
    return () => {
      setGenres({});
    };
```

This will cause the state to be set to an object every time this component unmounts. Objects are not an array, and so do not have the functions of an array. When the component mounts again, it will be an object still for a brief period, before it fetches from the API and it gets set back to an array again.

Instead, use:

```
    return () => {
      setGenres([]);
    };
```

Additionally, ensure that the default state where `genres` is initially declared (probably in the parent, or some ancestor) is set to an array otherwise it could be some other type before they are fetched from the API:

```
const [genres, setGenres] = useState([])
```

Off-topic but I'd also question if it's necessary to set it back to an empty array on unmount in the first place. Doing nothing would mean the old data is still there when this component remounts and the user would not need to wait for it to fetch again. The new data would replace once it arrives from the API. You could always implement a loading state to tell the user it is refreshing whilst not blocking them from seeing the "stale" data.